# How to use babel parsing class syntax

Tags: babel-loader

I want to use @babel/pase to parse class syntax,but i get a error when defined a method or declarant a variable

```
<script> 
    export default class view {
        data(){
            console.log('world');
        }
    }
</script>
```

get a error

```
Unexpected token, expected "}" (3:14)
```

babel.pase whit Plugins
`jsx typescript`

when I try to delete script is OK,but i want to why